# mysql, sql Update only if a record was found

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

The requirement is a conditional update where I'd want to update the record only if user row was found. Researched a lot on `WHERE EXISTS`, `IF`, and `CASE` but can't figure out a solution.

```
serviceRequest.sql = "SELECT @id:=id FROM user_token WHERE authToken = ?;\
     UPDATE user_token SET authToken = ? WHERE id = @id;";

serviceRequest.values = [request.query.authToken, "newToken"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use just the `UPDATE`.  There is no need for a `SELECT`:

```
UPDATE user_token
    SET authToken = ?
    WHERE authToken = ?;
```

Comment: I need a true or false result set in my query that's why select is required. `true` in case if record was found and token got updated and `false` if no matching record was found.

Comment: Why not just use `ROW_COUNT()` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).  That is the typical way of determining how many rows are updated.

Comment: In node-mysql, the response to your update query holds row_count() automatically, just pick it - as Gordon said no need to select something  @user2727195

Comment: ok, can we do something like IF(ROW_COUNT() >0) THEN UPDATE in sql queries without stored procedure etc.

Comment: No.  Just do the update.  Then do `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` to get the number of rows updated.  You can let the `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` do all the work.

Comment: You don't even need `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` thereafter, just take `affectedRows` from the queries response @user2727195